# Border getting applied to wrong element

Tags: html, css, css-position, nav

I've a side navbar with a `border-right` CSS. But the `border-right` is also getting applied to header. Even after using the `z-index` there was no result.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sideNav" class="visible-lg">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="active" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Content1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Content2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="header">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x37" alt="logo" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 70%;" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 20%">
    <label class="projTitle">App Name</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mainContent">
  <div class="body-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus efficitur congue diam, ut posuere ante. Proin sed ligula quis neque commodo accumsan. Ut vitae sollicitudin ex, consequat vestibulum lacus. Nullam volutpat turpis sed posuere faucibus.
    </p>       
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control {
  width: 95%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  color: #0b4faa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 0.02em solid #c1c1c1;
  z-index:508;
}

label.projTitle {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#sideNav {
  border-right: 0.02em solid #c1c1c1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:504;
}

#sideNav ul {
  margin-top: 70px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#sideNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  padding: 5%;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sideNav ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

#sideNav ul li:not(.active) a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-left-color: #337ab7;
}

.active a {
  color: #0b4faa;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#mainContent {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.body-content {
  margin: 0 45px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/abxnkveu/)</kbd>

Comment: Give your header a background-color. The border right is just showing through as it is currently transparent.

Comment: So elements have transparent background by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#header` a background color. Currently it's not set and thus transparent. Because of this elements "underneath" `#header` will show.

Comment: Should have given my comment as an answer... ;)

Comment: Thanks @allnodcoms but LuudJacobs answered first

Comment: @LuudJacobs So elements have transparent background by default ?

Comment: @Raviteja most elements have a _no_ background. Which appears as if it is a transparent one. There are quite a few exceptions though like `input` and `button` elements.

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

remove margin on ul & Add top position `#sideNav`

```
#sideNav {
    border-right: 0.02em solid #c1c1c1;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 504;
}
#sideNav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abxnkveu/2/

Comment: border not getting applied to the top empty space above first li when we scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Remove border from #sideNav and add to ul

```
#sideNav {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 504;
}
#sideNav ul {
    margin-top: 70px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 0.02em solid #c1c1c1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or

Remove margin-top from ul and add to #sideNav

```
#sideNav {
    margin-top: 70px;
    border-right: 0.02em solid #c1c1c1;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 504;
}
#sideNav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```